# Documentation for URDF2Gazebo parser in gzsdf

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The URDF2Gazebo parser used by gzsdf for converting URDFs to SDFs is a great tool, but currently hard to use due to the lack of documentation.

For example, I can add a ray sensor in URDF with the code below:

```
  <gazebo reference="cliff_sensor_right_link">
    <sensor:ray name="cliff_sensor_right">
      <alwaysActive>true</alwaysActive>
      <rayCount>50</rayCount>
      <rangeCount>1</rangeCount>
      <resRange>1.0</resRange>
      <minAngle>-0.04361</minAngle>
      <maxAngle>0.04361</maxAngle>
      <minRange>0.01</minRange>
      <maxRange>0.15</maxRange>
      <displayRays>true</displayRays>
    </sensor:ray>
  </gazebo>
```

However, I couldn't find information about how this translates to SDF and what options there are in general  (except checking the files by hand) .

Is there any documentation out there (wiki, API etc.)?

I was only able to locate the source code [here on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/0ddd1f60a8cd/gazebo/sdf/interface/parser_urdf.cc?at=default).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1551/documentation-for-urdf2gazebo-parser-in-gzsdf/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 129 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a tools section on the wiki that needs to be updated with information about gzsdf:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tools

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2017-05-30**:
This no longer exists